# Difference between the eden space usage values reported by jcmd and java.lang.management.MemoryUsage

Tags: java, memory-management

I want to monitor heap usage of my code using java.lang.management.MemoryUsage. In the example below, I create a bunch of entries in a HashSet and then inspect the heap usage. I was expecting to see a non-zero value for the used memory of eden space. To my surprise, I see a zero value for eden space usage and non-zero value for survivor space usage. 
This does not match with the heap info values printed by jcmd command, which shows non-zero usage of the eden space.
Can someone please help me understand the reason behind this?

I am using ParllelOldGC (-XX:+UseParallelOldGC), OpenJDK 11.0.2 on Linux.

I tried searching about this on various forums but could not find relevant information.

```
public HeapUsage() {
    System.out.println("Before ");
    printHeapUsage();
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<10000000; i++) {
        set.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }
    System.out.println("After");
    printHeapUsage();

}
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new HeapUsage();
    Thread.sleep(1000000);
}

private void printHeapUsage() {
    for (MemoryPoolMXBean mpbean :
         ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans()) {
        MemoryUsage usage = mpbean.getCollectionUsage();
        if (usage != null) {
            long max = usage.getMax();
            long used = usage.getUsed();            
            System.out.println(mpbean.getName() + " Used " + used + ", Max " + max);
        }
    }
}
```

**Java code output** -

Before 
PS Old Gen Used 0, Max 21473787904

PS Survivor Space Used 0, Max 89128960

PS Eden Space Used 0, Max 10558111744

After

PS Old Gen Used 0, Max 21473787904

PS Survivor Space Used 89096256, Max 89128960

**PS Eden Space Used 0, Max 10558111744**

**jcmd output** -

jcmd 45766 GC.heap_info
45766:
 PSYoungGen      total 611840K, used 541937K [0x0000000580100000, 0x00000005cac00000, 0x0000000800000000)

**eden space 524800K, 86% used** [0x0000000580100000,0x000000059bd44778,0x00000005a0180000)

from space 87040K, 99% used [0x00000005a0180000,0x00000005a5678040,0x00000005a5680000)

to   space 87040K, 0% used [0x00000005c5700000,0x00000005c5700000,0x00000005cac00000)

ParOldGen       total 1398272K, used 385048K [0x0000000080200000, 0x00000000d5780000, 0x0000000580100000)

object space 1398272K, 27% used [0x0000000080200000,0x0000000097a06000,0x00000000d5780000)

Metaspace       used 6287K, capacity 6411K, committed 6656K, reserved 1056768K

class space    used 586K, capacity 653K, committed 768K, reserved 1048576K

Answer (score 0):

I should have read the Javadoc carefully. [MemoryPoolMXBean.getCollectionUsage()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.management/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html#getCollectionUsage()) returns memory usage *after the most recent garbage collection*. It is normal for eden space to be empty after a GC. jcmd GC.heap_info gives the current heap usage (equivalent of [MemoryPoolMXBean.getUsage()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.management/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html#getUsage()). Therefore, in this example, jcmd output does not match with the output of code-snippet in the question.